# Create invoice when registrating

Tags: users, emails, commerce

I have a register form with some fields like `name shop, btw number, subscription, ...` . I want to create an invoice of the data filled in (do some operations with other variables). I know that there's a drupal module `Invoice` but how can I automatically create one when clicked on register button and send them to the users email? (I'm a drupal beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you the exact steps but I can suggest you some workaround for this.

You can use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module & create a rule for sending mail after event register.

You can send mail in action. Use [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) for mail formatting. Maybe you will need some Mail related modules such as [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) for sending mail.

Comment: Should I also could use the welcome mail (defined in account settings) instead of the Rules module?

Comment: Yes you can. Add this `$conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE;` in your `settings.php`

Comment: And what does that exactly does?